# how to get a apis output in python without json

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

here is api i am trying https://api.apithis.net/host2ip.php?hostname=google.com
as you can see unlike json apis it dose not have "" that you can copy as response.json

```
@client.command()
async def host(ctx, host):
    url = ('https://api.apithis.net/host2ip.php?hostname=' + host)

    response = requests.get(url)
    ipaddress = response.json()

    embed = discord.Embed(title="IP for website" + host, color=0x00ffff)
    embed.add_field(name="IP:", value=f'{ipaddress}', inline=True)                                                            
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

here is my current code if anyone can fix would help alot as im not sure how to use apis without json output thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the response you are getting is not JSON. If you see the `response header` then you can see it is
`content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`.

Now that it is not JSON you have to treat it as text.

```py
r = requests.get(url)
ipaddress = r.text if r.status_code == 200 else ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `Response.text` attribute

```py
reponse = requests.get(url).text # e.g 0.0.0.0
```